# Dynamical variables within for loop

Tags: bash, variables, for-loop

I have a simple bash script which print another csh script several times:

```
for j in $(seq 2 10)
do
printf "#!/bin/csh
set cnt    = ${j}

set cnt2   = ${j}+1 > "prod_${j}.ll"
done
```

Here each step of the loop I need to define cnt2 as "${j}+1" (e.g if j=2, cnt2 should be 3 etc)
and than go back to original $j, defining it value in the name of printed file

```
> "prod_${j}.ll"
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Probably the simplest is to use another variable, I have used `k` here:

```
for j in $(seq 2 10)
do
    k=$((j+1))
    printf "#!/bin/csh
set cnt    = ${j}

set cnt2   = ${k} > "prod_${j}.ll"\n"

done
```

It doesn't matter too much, but it hardly seems worth using `printf`, `echo` is a little simpler and does not require the trailing newline.  Equally the braces around the variable names are unnecessary here, but won't do any harm if you enjoy typing braces.

Comment: Yep, thank you it works! Will the script be more efficient if I change  "for loop" with the "while" loop?

Comment: I doubt it.  The biggest inefficiencies in shells scripts are usually over using external processes, the biggest culprit is the unnecessary use of `cat`.  Using `printf` can sometimes be inefficient since it is not built-in to all shells.  If my answer is acceptable, then please accept it as the solution.